# Stackdriver logging agent installation fails on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to google-fluentd stackdriver logging agent on my AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and it fails with the following error. Could anyone help?

```
*Job for google-fluentd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status google-fluentd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript google-fluentd, action "start" failed.
google-fluentd.service - LSB: data collector for Treasure Data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/google-fluentd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-10-08 08:18:33 IST; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 7778 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/google-fluentd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 google-fluentd[7778]:         from /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-0.14...red)>'
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 google-fluentd[7778]:         from /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `load'
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 google-fluentd[7778]:         from /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `<top (required)>'
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 google-fluentd[7778]:         from /usr/sbin/google-fluentd:7:in `load'
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 google-fluentd[7778]:         from /usr/sbin/google-fluentd:7:in `<main>'
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 google-fluentd[7778]:  * google-fluentd
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: data collector for Treasure Data.
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 08 08:18:33 ip-172-31-23-180 systemd[1]: google-fluentd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package google-fluentd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-fluentd-catch-all-config:
 google-fluentd-catch-all-config depends on google-fluentd (>= 1.3.0); however:
  Package google-fluentd is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package google-fluentd-catch-all-config (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-fluentd
 google-fluentd-catch-all-config
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*
```

Comment: What is invoking that output? Are you installing those package? If so, can you show the command line?

Comment: Following the instructions outlined in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#joint-install

Output is invoked when I try 
$ sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue.

There was an issue with the authentication configuration which was not mentioned in the stack driver configuration issue. Followed the [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/authorization) to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` do I need to add the stackdriver logging ones as well?